# Input data got reset after checkbox is checked when using Vue js

Tags: jquery, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a create new form with some input and group of checkboxes. Whenever I check on any of the options, all the input data will be reset. Please check the code below. 
I don't want my input to be reset like this. Can someone point out for me where i was wrong? I did google about this but most of the posts is about how can they reset form when the checkbox is checked.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#linktable',
  data () {
      return {
        info:[
      { name: 'Category1', value: '1' },
      { name: 'Category2', value: '2' },
      { name: 'Category3', value: '3' }
       ],
       
        checkName: [],
        ChannelName:'',
        Description:'',
        URL: '',

        
      }
    },
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<form autocomplete="off" id="linktable">
                <div class="form-group form-material">
                  <label for="inputText" class="form-control-label">Name</label>
                    <input input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Input Product Name" :value="ChannelName" id="AddNewChannelName"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group form-material">
                  <label for="inputText" class="form-control-label">Description</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Input Description" :value="Description" id="AddNewDescription"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group form-material">
                 
                    <label class="form-control-label">Category</label>
                    <div v-for="items in info"  >
                        <input type="checkbox"  :value="items.value"  v-model="checkName" >
                        <label >{{items.name}}</label>
                    </div>
                    <span>Checked names: {{ checkName }}</span>
                 
                </div> 
                </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the `:value` bindings and change them to `v-model` on your inputs. Like so:

```
<input input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Input Product Name" v-model="ChannelName" id="AddNewChannelName"/>
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Input Description" v-model="Description" id="AddNewDescription"/>
```

Your problem was that you were changing the values of your inputs back to `''`.   When you clicked on a checkbox Vue set your other inputs back to the values in your data object.